# How do I map each array item to a useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
for(const extra of fruit?.extras) {
        const [extra.label'Count', 'set'extra.label'Count'] = useState();
    };
```

Obviously this doesn't work at all, but I want to do something like this to map each array item to its own useState hook.

Comment: It is unsafe to map array items to individual hooks unless you can be 100% certain that the array is invariant for the lifetime of the component. [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) dictate ***"Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested function"***. Break rule this at your peril.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any trouble with using an array in useState()?

When you want to change an item in the array, create a new Array and add all the items to it. Then change that one item you want to change and pass that to set function. Example:

```
function App() {

const [state, setState] = useState([{ value: 1}, { value: 2 }]);

const onChange = (newValue, index) => {
   setState(prevState => {
   const temp = [...prevState];
   temp[index].value = newValue;
   return temp;
   });
}

return <div>
   {state.map((item, index) => <button key={index} onClick={() => onChange(item.value+1, index)}>{item.value}</button>)}
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks inside a loop. Hooks always use at the top level of your React function.